# Ionic 3 background image with a gradiant not working in device

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, gradient

I'm trying to set a background image with a gradient for ion-content in my ionic app. when I run ionic serve its working perfectly.But when its on device its not working.
Here is my css code is shown below

```
ion-content{
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: linear-gradient(#0000004b, black), url('../assets/imgs/wel2.png');

    }
```

How can i fix to work in device

Comment: Just trying same code in ionic in scss file but I am getting the error Invalid CSS after "...inear-gradient(": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#0000004b, black), "

Answer (score 0):

```
#element {
        background: linear-gradient(#0000004b, black); /* the standard */  
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0000004b, black); /* FF 3.6+ */  
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0000004b, black); /* IE10 */ 
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0000004b, black); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */  
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#0000004b, black); /* Opera 11.10 */  
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0000004b', endColorstr=black); /* IE6 & IE7 */  
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0000004b', endColorstr=black)"; /* IE8+ */
    }
```

check also the z-index of the #element